Send mail via M365 through PowerShell without compromising my Entra AD
I have been struggling with this for a while and maybe someone can provide me with some guidance. I have a bunch of scripts which run on my server periodically. At the end of the run I would like the scripts to send an email to an address in my M365 organization.
To do so I try to do an SMTP auth via PowerShell to one of my mailboxes (to use as a sender).
This fails with:

535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator

As a first solution I executed this on my M365 account:
Set-CASMailbox -Identity <EmailAddress> -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false

That did not change/solve the error.
After researching some more the only solution I was able to find is to turn off Azure Security Defaults. However that seems to have some red tape involved.
Is there not a solution for this that won't make me feel like I leave the front door open on my Azure AD / Entra AD?
Best regards

See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sending-smtp-from-o365-tenant/cebfd355-ede6-4c3e-b420-a06e968ecafe

The link promotes the solution that I want to avoid - disabling recommended security defaults for my whole Entra identity. Is there no other way?

Read the link response carefully.  There are other solutions in the link.  Disabling was the last resort when other options failed.
